# awk script on all the files in a folder

Tags: awk

I want to use an awk on all files I have in a folder by doing this:

```
awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\tMPC/K4me1"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6}' GSM*.bed > tmp $$ mv tmp GSM*.bed
```

Will I encounter some abnormalities? Will it do all files in such order, that `tmp` will be in fact unique for every file and there will be no overlaps?

I also get an error from `awk` when I use it:

```
awk: can't open file 12404
 input record number 21077683, file 12404
 source line number 1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code would expand the `GSM*.bed` expression to something like:

```
awk '...' GSM1.bed GSM2.bed ... > tmp $$ mv tmp GSM1.bed GSM2.bed
```

which does not make much sense. You can use `FILENAME` in awk, etc, to handle the files but it kind of gets complicated.

It might be better to loop through the files normally with a `while` loop and run `awk` for each one of them:

```
for file in GSM*.bed
do
   awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1, $2, $3, "MPC/K4me1", $4, $5, $6}' "$file" > tmp
   mv tmp "$file"
done
```

Note I used `OFS` to set the output field separator to the tab. This way, you don't have to hardcode it in your `print` command.

To use a variable, do use `-v` like this:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" -v your_var="$STR" '{print $1, $2, $3, "MPC/K4me1", $4, $5, $6, your_var}' "$file" > tmp
```

Comment: I have one more question, if I am an awk in a bash script, I define a variable  STR = "gig", how do I incorporate it into an awk print command? {print $1, $2, $3, "MPC/K4me1", $4, $5, $6, $STR}

Comment: @Tonja see my update, you have to use `-v` --> `awk -v STR="$STR" '{print STR}'`.